# System of equations and perturbation methods

Tags: systems-of-equations, perturbation-theory

I would like to characterise how the solution of a nonlinear system of equations change if a perturbation term is added.

Namely, I have the system
\begin{array}{lcl} 2y [F(x) - \varepsilon \frac{1}{y(xy-1)} ]  & = & 0 \\ y^2 [F^\prime (x) -\varepsilon \frac{y}{xy-1}] & = & 0\end{array}

In the unperturbed case $\varepsilon = 0$ the solution is handy $$ (x_0,0)$$ where $x_0$ is such that $F^\prime (x_0) = 0$.

How to describe the solution for small $\varepsilon$??

I would have tried to expand the perturbed terms around the solution of the unperturbed system, but the term $\frac{1}{y(xy-1)}$ is not even defined there.

Alternatively, following the perturbation theory one could assume that the perturbed solution can be expressed as
\begin{array}{lcl}   x & = & x_0 + \varepsilon f_1 +\varepsilon^2 f_2 + \dots \\ y = & =  & \varepsilon g_1 +\varepsilon^2 g_2 + \dots \end{array}

and let me substitute in the first equation of the system.
I get 
$$ 2(\varepsilon g_11 + \varepsilon^2 g_2 + \dots ) \Big[F(x_0+\varepsilon f_1 + \dots) - \varepsilon \frac{1}{(\varepsilon g_11 + \varepsilon^2 g_2 + \dots)((x_0+\varepsilon f_1 + \dots)(\varepsilon g_1 + \varepsilon^2 g_2 + \dots))}\Big]$$ which could develop into

$$2(\varepsilon g_1 + \varepsilon^2 g_2 + \dots )\Big[[F(x_0) + F ^{\prime \prime}(x_0)\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2 f_1^2]  - \varepsilon \frac{1}{x_0\varepsilon^2g_1^2 + x_0\varepsilon^3g_1g_2 + \varepsilon^3 f_1g_1^2 + \varepsilon^3x_0 g_1g_2 + \dots}\Big] $$

Now I need to collect terms that are first order in $\epsilon$.

But how to do that systematically?
I am struggling to handle the fraction $$- \varepsilon \frac{1}{x_0\varepsilon^2g_1^2 + x_0\varepsilon^3g_1g_2 + \varepsilon^3 f_1g_1^2 + \varepsilon^3x_0 g_1g_2 + \dots}$$

I would be most grateful for any hint.

Thanks and Happiest New 2019

**EDIT**:
I would like to describe one more attempt of mine.
I thought of replacing the original perturbed system
\begin{array}{lcl} 2y [F(x) - \varepsilon \frac{1}{y(xy-1)} ]  & = & 0 \\ y^2 [F^\prime (x) -\varepsilon \frac{y}{xy-1}] & = & 0\end{array}
with the system

\begin{array}{lcl} 2y [F(x) - \varepsilon (-\frac{1}{y}-x) ]  & = & 0 \\ y^2 [F^\prime (x) -\varepsilon (-y)] & = & 0\end{array}
using the approximations

$$\frac{1}{y(xy-1)} \approx -\frac{1}{y} -x$$ and $$ \frac{y}{xy-1} \approx -y$$ first-order valid around $y=0$.
Then I get something tractable, would this be a workaround?

**EDIT**
Following the comment by User121049, I would like to add, should it be of any interest, that the problem I have is equivalent to finding the stationary point of the function

$$ Z(x,y)  = y^2  \Big[ F(x) - \epsilon [\log(\frac{1}{y}-x) +1)] \Big]$$

the system I originally described is obtained by setting the partial derivatives to zero.

Comment: "How to understand what happens to the solution for small ϵ" -- what do you mean by "what happens"? Also, both perturbed and unperturbed case, any $(x, 0)$ seems to be a solution

Comment: I would like to know how the solution changes when $\epsilon$ is small, compared to case when $\epsilon$ is $0$. I do not understand how $(x,0)$ can be a solution in the perturbed case, as the term $\frac{1}{y(xy-1)} $ is not even defined for $y=0$.

Comment: At the end of the day, I would like to have a closed form solution of the nonlinear system. That looking unfeasible, I would be content in having a solution for "small" $\epsilon$.

Comment: Are you looking for the extrema of $y^2F(x)$ or is the form a coincidence?

Comment: It is not a coincidence,the unperturbed problem comes exactly for the minimisation problem you mentioned

Comment: I am wondering if the question is badly enough phrased to be unintelligible, or if otherwise anything else is wrong with it. Please let me know if that is the case.

Comment: @Anaedonist: Forgive me, but I am a bit confused why $y=0$ solves the system when $\varepsilon=0$... Your earlier comment stated that $1/y(xy-1)$ is not defined when $y=0$, which seems a bit different from your original question. May I ask if you allow the $y$ outside the bracket of your first equation cancel the $y$ in the denominator?

Comment: @hypernova, of course, you and the other user are right, there is a crucial mistake in the question. I will have to amend it, which I will do in due course, my apologies to all.

Comment: @Anaedonist: Never mind. Take your time and good luck to you :-)

Comment: I don't think your differentiation of $Z$ w.r.t. $y$ is correct. You should have a term like $2y(log(...)+1)$

Comment: Indeed the questions contain multiple errors. I am unable to delete it yet as the bounty is open. I will do it once it expires. My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $Z(x,y,\epsilon) = Z_0(x,y) + \epsilon Z_1(x,y)$. For $\epsilon=0$, stationary points of $Z = Z_0$ satisfy
$$
y^2 F'(x) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad 2 y F(x) = 0.
$$
Notice that *any* point $(x_0,0)$ obeys these equations, regardless of the value of $x_0$, as long as $x_0$ is in the domain of $F$. Furthermore, double roots of $F$ (for which $F(x_0) = 0$ and $F'(x_0) = 0$) are automatically stationary points of $Z_0$; therefore, the total set of stationary points of $Z_0$ consists of the union of lines
$$
\{(x,y)\;|\;y=0\} \,\cup\,\{(x,y) \;|\; F(x)=0\;\text{and}\;F'(x)=0\}.
$$

So far, so good. Now, however, we take a closer look at the perturbation
$$
 Z_1(x,y) = -y^2\left[1 + \text{log}\left(\frac{1}{y}-x\right)\right].
$$
Here, we encounter the problem that the logarithm is only defined when $\frac{1}{y}-x > 0$. This region in the plane is bounded by the hyperbolas $x y = 1$ and by the line $y=0$, it looks like this:

[image: domain of log]

In particular, the (orange) line $\left\{ (x,y)\,|\,y=0\right\}$ is on the *boundary* of the logarithm domain. However, the limit $\lim_{y \downarrow 0} Z_1(x,y)$ exists (check this!), so the horizontal axis is included in the domain of the logarithm. Furthermore, both limits $\lim_{y\downarrow 0} \frac{\partial Z_1}{\partial x}$ and $\lim_{y\downarrow 0} \frac{\partial Z_1}{\partial y}$ exist and are equal to zero (check this!), so the entire horizontal axis consists of stationary points of $Z_1$. We have just seen that the horizontal axis consists of stationary points of $Z_0$, so we conclude that the entire horizontal axis consists of stationary points of $Z = Z_0 + \epsilon Z_1$. This is true for **all** $\epsilon$, not necessarily small. No need for perturbation theory here.

What about the other stationary points of $Z_0$, that are characterised by double roots of $F$? Here, we *do* need perturbation theory. So, let's take a point $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $x_0$ is a double zero of $F$, i.e. $F(x_0) = 0$ and $F'(x_0)=0$. The value of $y_0$ is as yet unspecified. *However*, if we want to have any chance at all for $(x_0,y_0)$ to be a stationary point of $Z = Z_0 + \epsilon Z_1$, we must at the very least have that $(x_0,y_0)$ is in the **domain** of $Z_1$ -- otherwise it doesn't make any sense to talk about the value of $Z_1(x_0,y_0)$, because it doesn't exist. So, we must assume that $y_0$ is such that $(x_0,y_0)$ lies somewhere inside the blue region in the image above. Since we've covered the case $y_0 = 0$ already above, we have the following conditions on $(x_0,y_0)$:
$$
F(x_0) = 0,\quad F'(x_0) = 0,\quad \frac{1}{y_0} - x_0 > 0\quad\text{and}\quad y_0 \neq 0.
$$

*Only* for these points you can start to apply perturbation theory. As the perturbation is regular, you just have to substitute $x = x_0 + \epsilon x_1 + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ and $y = y_0 + \epsilon y_1 + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$, and expand the resulting expressions up to second order in $\epsilon$. I leave this up to you, but I can tell you that I get, at order $\epsilon$, the equations
$$
x_1 F''(x_0) + \frac{y_0}{1 - x_0 y_0} = 0
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{1-x_0 y_0}-2-2\,\text{log}\left(\frac{1}{y_0}-x_0\right) = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you Frits Veerman. As you might have realised form my comments above, I made some silly mistakes in my question that made it rather silly-looking. On the other hand you put some effort in your answer and I think is just fair to accept it. I would though be most happy if you could also consider the question I will post in 15 minutes, which was the one I originally intended.  Thanks again

Comment: No problem, you're welcome!